# Showing a column data from two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am stuck and wondering how do you show a table that has two column(City Name) based on two different foreign keys. In this case, I wanted to show a Manufacturer City AND a Warehouse City, while both of them will need to access CityID.

[image: ERD]

This is what i have came out with so far:

```
SELECT s.StkName, c.CityName AS "Manufacturer City", c.CityName AS 
"Warehouse City", s.SellingPrice FROM
STOCKITEM7364 s
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANUFACTURER7364 m ON m.ManID = s.ManID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CITY7364 c ON c.CityID = m.CityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN WAREHOUSE7364 w ON w.WHID = s.WHID AND w.CityID = c.CityID
WHERE s.StkName LIKE '%n' OR s.StkName LIKE '%e' OR s.StkName LIKE '%o' OR 
s.StkName LIKE '%p' OR s.StkName LIKE '%s';
```

I really do appreciate any helps or explanations regarding sql

Comment: Mysql or oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the city name table twice, once for the manufacturer and once for the warehouse. Try this:

```
SELECT s.StkName, cm.CityName AS "Manufacturer City", cw.CityName AS 
"Warehouse City", s.SellingPrice FROM
STOCKITEM7364 s
LEFT JOIN MANUFACTURER7364 m ON m.ManID = s.ManID
LEFT JOIN CITY7364 cm ON c.CityID = m.CityID
LEFT JOIN WAREHOUSE7364 w ON w.WHID = s.WHID
LEFT JOIN CITY7364 cw ON c.CityID = w.CityID
WHERE s.StkName LIKE '%n' OR s.StkName LIKE '%e' OR s.StkName LIKE '%o' OR 
s.StkName LIKE '%p' OR s.StkName LIKE '%s';
```

Note that `OUTER` is not required in `LEFT JOIN`.